Colouring arrows with Tikz (and adjust them)
I'm trying to draw some arrows with Tikz and I have two problems:

I want to color the arrows with \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}. How this can be done?
I also want that the arrows starting from the fraction begin in the rounded box. How can I do it?

With thanks. Please, find below my code:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,fit,arrows,shapes,backgrounds,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\begin{equation*}
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title} 
\frac{\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2pt,draw,rectangle,rounded corners,anchor=base] (a1){$A$}}}{\frac{\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2pt,draw,rectangle,rounded corners,anchor=base] (a2){$B$}}}{C}}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below right=1.7cm and 5.0cm of current page.center]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-.5ex]\node (b1) {{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}$a$}};};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below right=3.3cm and 5.0cm of current page.center]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-.5ex]\node (b2) {{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}$b$}};};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[->]<1-> (a1) edge [out=20, in=180] (b1);
    \path[->]<1-> (a2) edge [out=-20, in=180] (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Please only ask one question in each post.

Nesting tikz pictures is a bad idea.

You can access individual components of a beamer colour with e.g. title.fg:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,fit,arrows,shapes,backgrounds,shapes.geometric}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\begin{equation*}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title} 
\frac{\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2pt,draw,rectangle,rounded corners]{a1}{A}}{\frac{\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=2pt,draw,rectangle,rounded corners,]{a2}{B}}{C}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (b1) [title.fg,below right=1.7cm and 5.0cm of current page.center]{$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (b2) [title.fg,below right=3.3cm and 5.0cm of current page.center]{$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[->,title.fg]<1-> (a1) edge [out=20, in=180] (b1);
    \path[->,title.fg]<1-> (a2) edge [out=-20, in=180] (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


